# Maven seems not find a package which actually exist on https://mvnrepository.com/

Tags: maven, netbeans, apache-axis

@Pre: working under Linux Mint 20.4 + Netbeans 12.4 + Java JDK 8 + Maven + Axis2

I am learning about WSDL files so I used Axis2 engine to create a class from an WSDL file. No problem at this point.

Then I created a new Java Aplication proyect **WITH MAVEN** under Netbeans and imported the Axis2 generated class. After that I tryed to import Axis2 dependencies to my project by adding the dependencie to my pom.xml file. So I looked for it at "https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2" y copied and pasted in my pom the following text:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
    <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
    <version>1.8.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

However, when I try to import the package to my class as follows, I get a *"package org.apache.axis2 does not exist"* error

> import org.apache.axis2;

What am I doing wrong up to this point?

Thank you very much

EDIT: the problem is this dependency is pom type in version 1.2.0 and above. Version 1.1.1 is jar type (default type) so it works fine. I am still looking how to add the pom version as I need a newer version for my development

Comment: Are you sure you want to reference a POM, not a JAR?

Comment: I don't want to add a POM or a JAR. What I want to add y Axis2 1.8.0 dependency and I Still don't know how

Comment: First mvnrepository is not a usable Maven repository it's search engine which shows results. By default maven uses Maven Central where you can search via this: https://search.maven.org/  The given dependency can not work because it's parent module which does not contain the correct dependencies...

Comment: The correct search: https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.axis2

Comment: Then, mvnrepository is worthless as the results given by it are not usable anywhere.

Ok, the correct search is "https://search.maven.org/search?q=g:org.apache.axis2". But in this URL there are serveral links to download Axis2 jars. I don't need maven to download a jar and add it to my project. So what's the purpose of search.mave.org?

Is not possible to add the dependency to my pom and let maven do "its magic"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest manually adding dependencies to you pom.xml is somewhat error-prone. Just right-click on your "dependencies" node in NetBeans project explorer and click on "Add dependency". That's much easier.

Comment: Thank you very much. But just a comment: I don't know why but using your method with axix2 1.8.0 didn't work. Maven didn't find the dependency although in https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.axis2/axis2 exist. I had to use an older version

Comment: Maybe 1.8.0 isn't compatible with JDK 8. JDK 8 is quite old. You should at least use JDK 11 because that's the current stable version.